# Combining 'Isblank Status' with an imbedded 'IF' statement

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to combine the following two statements together and struggling to combine them.

The first one is checking the outcome of survey questions where the outcome is either `"Pass"` or `"Fail"`.

The second one is if the overall questionnaire column is blank (the survey has not been filled in yet), I would like the cell to be populated with `""` (blank, not show anything.  Currently I am seeing `"Fail"`)

1st Formulae:

```
=IF((AND(H18="No",I18="Yes",J18="No",K18="Yes",L18="2 Metres",M18="Yes",N18="Yes",O18="Yes",P18="Yes",Q18="Yes")),"Pass","Fail")
```

2nd Formulae:

```
=if(and(isblank(H2:Q2))," ",)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Regards
Caroline

Comment: Someone has a suggested edit for you but it's honestly not clear to me whether you want the cell to just be blank or whether you want it to literally say 'blank'. You seem to be asking for both things so I can't tell if the suggested edit conflicts with your intent or not. Can you edit your question so it's clear which one you mean?

Comment: Caroline, if the answer below has addressed your question, please check it off as an answer, to help others with a similar question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this combination works:

```
=IF((AND(H18="No",I18="Yes",J18="No",K18="Yes",L18="2 Metres",M18="Yes",N18="Yes",O18="Yes",P18="Yes",Q18="Yes")),"Pass",if(COUNTA(H18:Q18),"Fail","blank"))
```

If they enter something, but not correctly, they "Fail", if they entered everything correctly, they "Pass", and if it is blank, this shows "blank".
You can change "blank" to "" (ie. empty quotes) if you don't want anything shown for a blank record.

Here is a sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rGCeNF_Eje7UrpM3PK9YTk_3ZKBo1qOAVEVoRVmqyRs/edit?usp=sharing

Please check back here and flag if this answers your question, to help others in the future.  If not, please clarify what's missing.

Note that this may not be the most efficient way of handling your survey responses, since the correct answers are all 'hard coded' into the formula.  If it makes sense for you, it might be better to have the correct answers stored as a list - one answer per question - so that you could add or change questions in the future, without having to change the formula.  If that's what you'd like, share a COPY of your sheet, with any sensitive data removed, and set the SHARE options to allow anyone to edit.